# How Jenkins Maven deploy Plugin works

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a java project I'm working on, and so far I've used `mvn deploy` to upload artifacts to nexus. As far as I can tell, Maven looks at the `distributionManagement` element in the POM and, if the current version is a snapshot, it uploads to the repository configured as snapshot, otherwise it uploads to the release repository. For this to work, both need to be configured in the POM.

What I'd like to know is if this behavior is the same with Jenkins Maven Integration Plugin. Do I need to set both repositories within the POM? If not, how can it know when to upload to snapshot repo and when to release repo (since it only asks for 1 URL or ID)?

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same with Jenkins Maven integration plugin.
You are suposed to specify same things at pom.xml

Comment: but the plugin asks for a repository URL and ID, why would it ask for it again if they're in the pom?